# ListPopupWindow over keyboard

Tags: android

I have built an TextSuggest component with an EditText and a ListPopupWindow. This component is in a Dialog. My problem is that when i click on the EditText to filter the list, the ListPopupWindow covers the keyboard. I would like that the keyboard reduced the ListPopupWindow, like int YouTube app or twitter app. I have tried to use the method ListPopupWindow.setSoftInputMode(adjustResize) but it doesn't work. Could you please help me?

Below is the screen shot of what I am talking about:
http://instagram.com/p/poK-wULH3A/

Comment: Are you using spinner ?

Answer (score 2):

There's a specific method to call, you set it once when create Popup before showing it:

```
mPopup.setInputMethodMode(ListPopupWindow.INPUT_METHOD_NEEDED);
```

> Control how the popup operates with an input method: one of `INPUT_METHOD_FROM_FOCUSABLE`, `INPUT_METHOD_NEEDED`, or `INPUT_METHOD_NOT_NEEDED`. 
>   If the popup is showing, calling this method will take effect only the next time the popup is shown or through a manual call to the show() method.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

Comment: It doesn't work, i have used : this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE), and it works slightly better. Anyway this is the way to go, thank you very much!!